# Java String remove all characters after number

Tags: java

This is my string address : London, Jon 2 A

And I want to see in my output see  London, Jon

I tried to do this :

```
String result = chapterNumber.substring(0, chapterNumber.indexOf("1"));
```

But I have to do 10 times from different number maybe is better way to do this

Comment: It is called regular expression (regex).

Comment: @Flown ok but sometimes my address is   London, Jon 2A And I want to remove 2A

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this

```
     String str = "London, Jon 2 A";
     System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\d.*",""));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regex` with groups to get only the first group (the sequence of non-digit chars until the first digit):

```
String result = chapterNumber.replaceAll("([^\\d])(\\d.*)", "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "London, Jon 2 A";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(s);
matcher.find();
int i = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group());

System.out.println(s.substring(0,s.indexOf(String.valueOf(i))));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String result = chapterNumber.substring(0, chapterNumber.indexOf(","));
```